# Do you get charged when you put a Heroku app in maintenance mode?

Tags: heroku

I have an app, with some services etc on Heroku.
When i put it in maintenance mode, do I still get charged for it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would get charged for any running processes that you have running at the normal rate.  Maintenance mode is simply a message to the router asking it to not route requests into your application.

```
$  heroku ps                                                                                                                      
Process  State         Command                               
-------  ------------  ------------------------------------  
web.1    running for 25h  bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./.. 

$  heroku maintenance:on                   
Maintenance mode enabled.

$  heroku ps                                                                                                                      
Process  State         Command                               
-------  ------------  ------------------------------------  
web.1    running for 25h  bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./..
```

Answer (score -1):

You would not be charged if there are no processes being used however I suspect if you have other paid addons that you would still be charged for them.

Comment: 'No processes being used' meaning you've scaled them down to zero